# mb_detect_encoding() missing in PHP?

Tags: php

Using PHP 5.6.13 Windows CLI from http://windows.php.net/download#php-5.5, this:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php'; //V1.5

$html = file_get_html('http://google.com');
```

fails with

```
Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()
```

and SO suggests this is due to the multibyte string extension missing. Indeed phpinfo() says

```
Zend Multibyte Support => disabled
```

which is is a surprise and disappointment.

What's the remedy? I want to remain with an official build.

Comment: Just enable the mbstring extension. Use `<?php echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` to check which php.ini you have to edit and then put `extension=php_mbstring.dll` in that file.

Comment: Thanks. That failed with "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\php_mbstring.dll' - The specified module could not be found." until I copied the module there, but how do I get PHP to reference the module in the supplied location, .\ext ?

Comment: By setting the [extension_dir=... directive](http://docs.php.net/ini.core#ini.extension-dir).

Comment: VolkerK, thanks. I found that for some unfathomable reason the extension_dir line for the default install was commented-out on the default development php.ini. Once fixed http://i.imgur.com/nCm2dmO.png , all was fine.

Comment: VolkerK, please place your answer so I can tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build package from windows.php.net contains everything you need to run the [mbstring extension](http://docs.php.net/mbstring); it's just not enabled by default.

- use `<?php echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` to check which php.ini you have to edit
- make sure the [extension_dir=...](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir) directive points to the `{yourPHPDir}/ext` directory
- add or uncomment* the line [extension=](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension)php_mbstring.dll
- (if php runs as a httpd module: restart the webserver; not the case here)

---

*) any line starting with a `;` or (before php 7) `#` is concidered a comment.